# How to write complex DSL query in Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, elasticsearch-5, kibana-6

This is what I have used for creating index in multi field mapping

```
curl -X PUT http://localhost:9200/mapping_log
{ "mappings":{ "properties":{"data1:{"type": "text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword"}}}, {"data2":{"type": "text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword"}}}, {"data3":{"type": "text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword"}}}, } } }
```

This is my data in my elastic search and I want to do search like for example when I search for support I should get values  data and server and when I search for  developer I should get geo and graph , and I want suggester for data3 like suppose if I enter g then I should get option of graph and geo ,,can someone help me with this ..

```
{
        "took": 14,
        "timed_out": false,
        "_shards": {
            "total": 1,
            "successful": 1,
            "skipped": 0,
            "failed": 0
        },
        "hits": {
            "total": {
                "value": 4,
                "relation": "eq"
            },
            "max_score": 1,
            "hits": [
                {
                    "_index": "mapping_log",
                    "_type": "properties",
                    "_id": "1",
                    "_score": 1,
                    "_source": {
                        "data1": "support",
                        "data2": "data",
                        "data3": "datapos"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "_index": "mapping_log",
                    "_type": "properties",
                    "_id": "2",
                    "_score": 1,
                    "_source": {
                        "data1": "support",
                        "data2": "server",
                        "data3": "serverpos"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "_index": "mapping_log",
                    "_type": "properties",
                    "_id": "3",
                    "_score": 1,
                    "_source": {
                        "data1": "developer",
                        "data2": "graph",
                        "data3": "graphpos"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "_index": "mapping_log",
                    "_type": "properties",
                    "_id": "4",
                    "_score": 1,
                    "_source": {
                        "data1": "developer",
                        "data2": "geo",
                        "data3": "geopos"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [edge_ngram tokenizer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-edgengram-tokenizer.html) along with the [source filtering](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/search-request-source-filtering.html)

Adding a working example with index data (Same as that of question), index mapping, search query and search result

**Index Mapping:**

```
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "my_analyzer": {
          "tokenizer": "my_tokenizer"
        }
      },
      "tokenizer": {
        "my_tokenizer": {
          "type": "edge_ngram",
          "min_gram": 1,
          "max_gram": 10,
          "token_chars": [
            "letter",
            "digit"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "data1": {
        "type": "text"
      },
      "data2": {
        "type": "text"
      },
      "data3": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer":"my_analyzer"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Query:**

> when I search for support I should get values data and server

```
{
  "_source": [
    "data2"
  ],
  "query": {
    "multi_match": {
      "query": "support",
      "fields": [
        "data1",
        "data2"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "67260491",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 1.4094054,
        "_source": {
          "data2": "server"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "67260491",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "4",
        "_score": 0.44183272,
        "_source": {
          "data2": "data"
        }
      }
    ]
```

---

**Search Query:**

```
{
  "_source": [
    "data2"
  ],
  "query": {
    "multi_match": {
      "query": "developer",
      "fields": [
        "data1",
        "data2"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
 "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "67260491",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "2",
        "_score": 1.0296195,
        "_source": {
          "data2": "graph"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "67260491",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "3",
        "_score": 1.0296195,
        "_source": {
          "data2": "geo"
        }
      }
    ]
```

---

**Search Query:**

> I want suggester for data3 like suppose if I enter g then I should get
> option of graph and geo

```
{
  "_source": [
    "data3"
  ],
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "data3": "g"
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "67260491",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "3",
        "_score": 1.1123568,
        "_source": {
          "data3": "geopos"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "67260491",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "2",
        "_score": 0.99270093,
        "_source": {
          "data3": "graphpos"
        }
      }
    ]
```

---

**Update 1:**

You can update the index mapping as

```
PUT /<index-name>/_mapping

{
  "properties": {
    "data2": {
      "type": "text",
      "fields": {
        "keyword": {
          "type": "keyword"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: getting :-  type": "mapper_parsing_exception while executing index_mapping

Comment: @Nitesh which version of Elasticsearch are you using ?

Comment: @Nitesh you cannot update your old index mapping, you need to create a new index with the new index mapping, add the data into it and then run the search queries. Please let me know if you are able to create the index ?

Comment: version of elasticsearch is 7.12.0 , I am facing issue with creating new index , can u help me with that , and another part is data3 suggester should find the values according to the selection of data2

Comment: @Nitesh are you trying to update your previous index mapping ? You need to create a new index with the index mapping given above in the answer --> https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-create-index.html

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231595/discussion-between-escoder-and-nitesh).

Comment: if data2 is duplicate then how to discard it let only one to display ..

data1        data2       data3
Developer    GEO         GeoPosData
Developer    GEO         GeoPos
Developer    GRAPH       GraphPos
Support      SERVER      ServerPos
Support      Data        DataPos

Comment: @Nitesh you need to modify your index mapping for the `data2` field. This field should have both text and keyword type (you can do this using multi-fields). Then you need to use `collapse` parameter to remove duplicates from the search result

Comment: again have to create new indexmapping

Comment: @Nitesh no need to create the index mapping again, you can just update your existing index mapping, and then run the new search query using the `collapse` parameter. Go through the updated part of the answer

Comment: Let us continue this discussion in chat